# Pandas store a nested object using mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I want to store a dataframe in mongodb. I am able to do that normally, but I need to add another column with values to be stored as an object in mongodb as

```
Column C:
 1.   {
    "test1": "Unknown",
    "test2": "Unknown"
    }
 2.   {
    "test1": "Unknown",
    "test2": "Unknown"
    }
```

I am trying to do this by:

```
df['C'] = {
    "test1": "Unknown",
    "test2": "Unknown"
    }
```

This is giving me an error as

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I will be storing this in mongodb later using

```
records = json.loads(df.T.to_json()).values()

db.users.insert(records)
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your dataframe isn't one row long, so you can't assign a single value to df['C'].
You could make a list of the same length as the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(5)), columns=["Sample"])
df['C'] = [{"test":"value"}]* df.shape[0]
df

    Sample  C
0   0   {'test': 'value'}
1   1   {'test': 'value'}
2   2   {'test': 'value'}
3   3   {'test': 'value'}
4   4   {'test': 'value'}
```

or use apply to run some function which populates the column:

```
df['C'] = df['Sample'].apply(lambda x: {'test{}'.format(x):'Unknown'})
df

    Sample  C
0   0   {'test0': 'Unknown'}
1   1   {'test1': 'Unknown'}
2   2   {'test2': 'Unknown'}
3   3   {'test3': 'Unknown'}
4   4   {'test4': 'Unknown'}
```

Using apply has the advantage of being able to easily drop existing data from the dataframe into the new column. For example here the number for test is being passed in from the "Sample" field.

Comment: oh i see. Then why does a normal df['C'] = 'Unknown" work? This assigns all rows as Unknown

Comment: Probably because a dictionary is an iterable. Assigning a list won't work either, e.g. df['C']=['c']. While a string is technically an iterable, it's not a collection in the same way a list or a dictionary is. In other words, if you try to assign a collection of things to a pandas column, pandas tries to iterate over it and assign each value to a row. In your case, you've got more rows than values, so pandas gives out about not having enough.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. This is just my best guess, so if you need more info I'd suggest checking [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). I actually didn't even known you could do df['C']="somestring" and it'd assign that string to every row in the column.